# Symfony 1.4 Adding id to sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

What I'm wanting to do is inject a unique id for each row in a form. It's easy to customize the form layout using sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter but not inject a unique id for a row.

Basically wanting to do something like this:

```
<?php

class sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterCustom extends sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter {

    protected
            $rowFormat = "<div id=\"row_%form_field_name%\">%error% \n %label% \n %field%%help% %hidden_fields%</div>\n",

}
```

Seems like it would be an intuitive feature but have poured through the API's and discussions and haven't found an example of someone doing it. Would make like a whole lot easier for interactive forms.

Comment: Why don't you use Symfony 2.x ?

Comment: It's a massive existing site and would take an extremely long time to migrate to 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

```
class sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterTwitterBootstrap extends sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatter
{    
   // ...
   // here is some your code
   // ...
   public function __construct(sfWidgetFormSchema $widgetSchema)
   {
       foreach ($widgetSchema->getFields() as $field) {
           if (get_class($field) == 'sfWidgetFormInputText') {
              $field->setAttribute('id', 'whatever-id');
           }
       }
       parent::__construct($widgetSchema);
   }
   // ...
   // here is some your code
   // ...

}
```

Here you can iterate thru all your form elements and check all parameters. 
I did like that for my Twitter Bootstrap formatter when migrated to TB 3.0 from TB2 - they needed field class 'form-control' for every input field.
Here is how I did that: http://www.alexfilatov.com/2014/01/07/symfony-1-4-twitter-bootstrap-3-0-form-formatter/

Comment: That's a great start. Since the id is unique to each field, I'm still having a problem in that I can't access the attribute from formatRow since there isn't an instance of sfWidgetFormSchema for the field I am trying to set the id on. Is there a way to pass an additional value to formatRow?